# Делегаты путаница в названии

Tags: c#, делегаты

групповые и комбинированные делегаты это одно и то же?

Comment: Контекст какой-то есть или вопрос из вакуума?

Comment: Групповые делегаты? Первый раз о таком слышу. Может быть вы имеет в виду method group?

Comment: @andreycha, скорее multicast

Comment: @Grundy без пояснений автора -- гадание на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 1):

В MSDN действительно есть упоминание "групповой делегат" в описании [MultycastDelegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.multicastdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx).  В других источниках используется также понятие "комбинированный делегат", что по сути является синонимом. Как всегда проблема возникла из-за различных вариантов перевода одного и того же понятия - учите английский хотя бы до `English.Level = readonly` =)

В настоящий момент все делегаты .NET наследуются от `MultycastDelegate`.
В подтверждение - статья Джона Скита [Delegates and Events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx)
для читающих только на русском, перевод на хабре: [Делегаты и события в .NET](https://habrahabr.ru/post/198694/)